# Why use a Schottky diode instead of a normal diode on a solar panel?

Tags: diodes, solar-cell, schottky

I see all forums recommending using a Schottky diode instead of a "normal" 1N4007 diode in parallel with each solar panel cell. Why a Schottky? You don't need speed here - and the voltage drop is about the same (0.7V-1V).)

Schottky forward voltage (drop): [PDF1](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwju9vni_dbNAhVICZoKHRJmCQMQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vishay.com%2Fdocs%2F81857%2F1n4148.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHz9lcl4UOYzJYbvhlQfYXOTES6kg&sig2=Rzo5dbDa7t9nj2IfZ1QXxQ), [PDF2](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/1N4148_1N4448.pdf), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N4148)

Comment: what makes you think the voltage drop is the same? 0.6-0.7 is a std diode,  0.15-0.45 is scottky. Operating current dependent

Comment: @JonRB-Wikipedia and the link provided shows forward voltage around 1V for scottky

Comment: That's not a Schottky diode, try a 1N5... part.

Comment: @pjc50 - Thanks! That was my problem. Solved!

Comment: Check this diode. https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBR20100CT-D.PDF

Comment: @AbdullahBaig - the voltage drop is 0.75V for your diode.

Comment: That is with 10 A passing through it. A general purpose silicon diode with a similar current rating would have 1.1~1.2 V for 10 A. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the voltage drop is not about the same.  Schottky diodes have half the voltage drop compared to otherwise equivalent full silicon diodes.  And, that's the reason.

When a solar cell is dark, it is simply a silicon diode.  The diode polarity is opposite the current flow when illuminated.  For a series string of solar cells, a single cell in the dark blocks the current regardless of what the other cells are doing.  Even worse, with enough other cells in series, the cell in the dark can be reverse biased to the point of destruction.  A Schottky diode in parallel allows the current from other cells to bypass a dark cell, and limits the reverse bias voltage to a safe level.

Answer (score 2):

Schottky diodes have higher series resistance then regular silicon diodes. The also have lower reverse breakdown voltage.

Due to the Rs of Schottky diode the voltage drop advantage can be mostly nullified at higher currents.

The lower reverse breakdown voltage can make Schottky diodes more vunerable to ESD / nearby lightning, or system induced voltage surge damage.

Number one failure cause of bypass diodes is overheating due to insufficient heat sinking of diode when panel is partially shaded.  Leaded pellet diodes have poor ability to dissipate heat.  Better to use TO220 or similar packaged diodes with additional (electrically isolated) metal heat sinking.